# ExtJS 6.2 treeviewdragdrop Cannot read property 'attributes' of null

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I've got this error when I try to drag and drop a row inside a treeview:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of null
at constructor.updateColumns (ext-all-debug.js:205002)
at constructor.handleUpdate (ext-all-debug.js:204830)
at constructor.onUpdate (ext-all-debug.js:181917)
at constructor.fire (ext-all-debug.js:20731)
at constructor.doFireEvent (ext-all-debug.js:21700)
at constructor.prototype.doFireEvent (ext-all-debug.js:58105)
at constructor.fireEventArgs (ext-all-debug.js:21553)
at constructor.fireEvent (ext-all-debug.js:21512)
at constructor.onCollectionItemChange (ext-all-debug.js:91973)
at constructor.notify (ext-all-debug.js:74624)
```

Here is my plugin configuration:

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
    appendOnly: true,
    sortOnDrop: true,
}]
```

I use Ext JS 6.2.0.981. What is possible wrong? Isn't it bug in ExtJS?
I have no idea what to do. I've tried different options in plugin config.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and I found the solution.
In my case, the problem was in renderer of name column in treeView. Problematic renderer:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            if(value !== '')
            {
                if(record.raw.mapped === true)
                {
                    metaData.tdStyle = 'background-color:#c3e79d';
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

When I changed to :

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            if(value !== '')
            {
                if(record.data.mapped === true)
                {
                    metaData.tdStyle = 'background-color:#c3e79d';
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
```

Everything worked. The problem was because dropped object didn't have **record.raw** but **record.data** attribute!